# String fails to paste in the new iPython 5.0

Tags: python, string, ipython, non-ascii-characters

In the python 2.7 console, as well as iPython 4, I was able to paste this string into a variable like so:

```
In [2]: c = 'ÙjÌÉñõµÏ“JÖq´ž#»&•¼²nËòQZ<_'
```

Subsequently I could type:

`In [3]: print(c)` and it would return `ÙjÌÉñõµÏ“JÖq´ž#»&•¼²nËòQZ<_`

However, in iPython 5.0, I get the following error:

```
In [4]: c = 'ÙjÌÉñõµ^LÏ“JÖq´ž#»&•¼²nËòQZ<_'
  File "<ipython-input-4-9bf9f2fa5210>", line 1
    c = 'ÙjÌÉñõµ

^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Even `%paste` returns an error:

```
    ÙjÌÉñõµ
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What changed in iPython from 4 to 5, and why is this occurring? Something to do with the string not having escaped quotes?

Comment: Changing the `^L` to `\^L` makes it accept it, but that sequence is missing from `c`.  It's as though the new `readline` code is interpreting the `^L` as a control character.  It shouldn't.

Comment: What's the source of this string?  How many characters?  What's it supposed to represent?

Comment: 32 characters. It's the ciphertext from DES encryption on a given plaintext and key and iv.

Comment: If I `ctrl v` that string on a plain `python2.7` session and ask `len(c)` I get 46.  And if I add `u` (unicode) to it, I get 27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.jupyter.org/2016/07/08/ipython-5-0-released/

Ipython5 replaced the default `readline` with a new  prompt_toolkit.

It looks like your string has several characters that the old readline ignored, but the new one sees.  The first occurs right after the `µ`.  I don't see it in the SO windows, but I can 'feel it' when moving the cursor over the line.  I can also see something when pasting the line into an editor.  But I not familiar enough with raw text tools to see more.

When I paste your string into a plain Python shell I get a bell and the screen clears.  So even the regular `readline` is having problems with this string.

I've added '|' were there are unprintable characters

```
c = 'ÙjÌÉñõµ|Ï“JÖq´ž#|»&•¼|²nËòQZ<_'
```